# Scala: Iterate an Array's indices in for-comprehension but ensure result type is same Array type

Tags: scala, sequence, for-comprehension, resulttype

I know that the sequence type of the first sequence found in a for-comprehension defines the output type of the comprehension. But I need to get around this without sacrificing the use of comprehension syntax.

Suppose I have some `Array[Double]` called `v` and some complicated predicate function called `condition` that is based on the *indices* of `v`, and if `condition(i)` evaluates to true, then I want to keep the element of `v`. It's similar to using `filter`, except the filtering happens on the indices, not on the values of `v`.

I want to express this efficiently with a for-comprehension over the indices, but I want the type of the result to be `Array[Double]` and not whatever is the type of `Array.indices`.

Here's a minimal example where `condition` is just a toy example of calculating whether an index is even. Real use cases involve checking indices in a 2D array where certain image gradient conditions are true, but the idea is the same as this simple example.

```
scala> val v = Array[Double](8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0)
v: Array[Double] = Array(8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0)

scala> def condition(x: Int): Boolean = {x % 2 == 0} // but could be complex
condition: (x: Int)Boolean

scala> for (i <- v.indices if condition(i)) yield v(i)
res136: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double] = Vector(8.0, 10.0, 12.0)
```

The output of the for-comprehension is of type `scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double]` but I am seeking how to ensure it will just be `Array[Double]`, without needing an explicit type cast.

Basically, if I iterate from `foo.indices`, and the items yielded come from `foo(i)`, I am seeking a way to automatically use the type of `foo` for the result, so that the container type matches whatever type's indices were iterated over.

What is the right idiom in Scala for ensuring the result type of a for-comprehension that needs to specifically range over indices, but where the container type of the result should match the container type of the thing-whose-indices-are-being-used instead of the type of the indices sequence itself (which is inconsequential for the comprehension)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `zipWithIndex`. In case of `Array`, it will produce `Array[(Double, Int)]`, not some strange `IndexedSeq`:

   ```
   for ((a, i) <- v.zipWithIndex if condition(i)) yield a
   ```
2. Use `breakOut`

   ```
   import collection.breakOut
   val res: Array[Double] = (
     for (i <- v.indices if condition(i)) yield v(i)
   )(breakOut)
   ```
3. Just convert the result in the end with `toArray`, optimize it later when it turns out to be really necessary.
4. Also note that `zipWithIndex` can be defined in general for all collections that have a [Traverse](https://typelevel.github.io/cats/api/cats/Traverse.html#zipWithIndex[A](fa:F[A]):F[(A,Int)]) typeclass. It is a general method to convert `F[A]` into an `F[(A, Int)]` under assumption that there is a `Traverse[F]` available.

Comment: `zipWithIndex` looks like a good approach. The third approach likely won't work because some of this needs to be generalized in a function which might receive an `Array`, an `ArrayBuffer`, a `List`, etc., and I don't want any code that attempts to manually pick out the input type and convert to that type at the end .. I need something that implicitly does that by representing the indices with a container of the same type as the parent object the indices are coming from.